# How to plot the Standard Normal CDF in R?

Tags: r

As the title says, I'm trying to plot the CDF of a N(0,1) distribution between some values a, b. I.e. Phi_0,1 (a) to Phi_0,1 (b). For some reason I'm having issues finding information on how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `curve` to do the plotting, `pnorm` is the normal probability (CDF) function:

```
curve(pnorm, from = -5, to = 2)
```

[image]

Adjust the `from` and `to` values as needed. Use `dnorm` if you want the density function (PDF) instead of the CDF. See the `?curve` help page for a few additional arguments.

Or using `ggplot2`

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data.frame(x = c(-5, 2)), aes(x = x)) +
  stat_function(fun = pnorm)
```

[image]

Generally, you can generate data and use most any plot function capable of drawing lines in a coordinate system.

```
x = seq(from = -5, to = 2, length.out = 1000)
y = pnorm(x)
```

Comment: `ggplot(data.frame(x = c(-5, 2)), aes(x)) + stat_function(fun = pnorm)`

Comment: Great, thanks! But what if I want to plot this curve alongside actual data? Using the standard plot function and curve function together?

Comment: In base R, the first time you start a plot it creates a new plot. Then there are ways to draw on top of that. If you use `curve` as I show, it creates a new plot, and you could then use `points()` or `lines()` to add more data to it. Or, if you already have a plot that you want to add the curve to, use the `add = TRUE` argument to `curve()`, and it will draw on top of the current plot  instead of creating a new plot.